# LED wont turn on using localtime [ARDUINO]

Tags: c, arduino, led, localtime

```c
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <time.h>

time_t now;
struct tm *now_tm;
int h,m,s;

void setup(){
    pinMode(D6,OUTPUT);
}

void loop ()
{
    now = time(NULL);
    now_tm = localtime(&now);
    h = now_tm->tm_hour;
    m = now_tm->tm_min;
    s = now_tm->tm_sec;

    if(h == 17 && m == 0 && s==0)
    {
        digitalWrite(D6,HIGH);
        delay(100000);
        digitalWrite(D6,LOW);
    }
}
```

I don't know why my LED on pin D6 won't turn on when it's 17:00:00

I tried check it with other `IF` condition and it worked fine

I count the hour, the minute and the second on visual and they showed the right value

Comment: How is Arduino supposed to know what time is it? Put a `Serial.println("Debug message");` inside the if so you can see if you are actually entering the condition block (which most likely you are not)

Comment: what is D6? Uno, Nano, Mega doesn't have D6 constant

Comment: What other condition did you try that worked?

Comment: what library are you using? what real time clock?

Answer (score 0):

In order for your code to work, you need to have some type of external clock (arduino doesn't know what time it is) e.g. DS3231. You can find tutorial about it here: https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-ds3231-real-time-clock-tutorial/